# Kibana: Unwanted double sorting (why is my saved search sorted by @timestamp?)

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elk

we have a classic ELK setup and created a dashboard to view log messages.
we want to sort the log messages by the timestamp in the log file, but in the moment it is sorted by insert time (or is it the filebeats read time?)

Columns:

- @timestamp: insert time
- Timestamp: the parsed log timestamp

I tried to change the log sorting in the dashobard but this leads to weird effects.
After a little digging i found out: the data is sorted now by 2 columns: @timestamp and Timestamp.

So the question is: Why is it sorted by @timestamp at all and how to avoid it?
(Or i could avoid the problem by brute forcing filebeats to put the Timestamp value into @timestamp. but i really would like to understand the problem...)

screenshot of the created elastic query (from a aved search) by kibana:
[image: Saved search in dashboard]

BTW: the Timestamp column is configured in the index mapping as time filter field

[image: time filter fiels]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem: The saved query was sorted by the "invisible" column "@timestamp".

Solution:

- adding the column "@timestamp" again
- set the sorting to "Timestamp"
- removing the sorting by "@timestamp"
- removing the column "@timestamp" again

Answer (score 0):

EDIT

Someone must've manually sorted the column & saved the report:
[image]

---

ORIGINAL

I think you've selected one of those when you created your Kibana index pattern. This should do the trick:

[image]

And then either the first or the last option:

[image]